# what is the guid-like id associated with a dynamic proxy in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out an exception, and wondering how the id for an Entity object is generated:

System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.TaskInstance_EFB25059687D16F3AB6ABF93C582495406916AC2CC28E7E312CB6B50EC3CF7A5.get_TaskLogs()

TaskInstance is the Entity here. It has the same identifier every time the exception happens. Just wondering how it works underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehwere in EF's code base concerning proxy type generation, there is this method ...

```
// <summary>
// Creates an SHA256 hash of a description of all the metadata relevant to the creation of a proxy type
// for this entity type.
// </summary>
private string BuildEntityTypeHash()
{
    using (var sha256HashAlgorithm = MetadataHelper.CreateSHA256HashAlgorithm())
    {
        var hash = sha256HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(BuildEntityTypeDescription()));

        // convert num bytes to num hex digits
        var builder = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
        foreach (var bite in hash)
        {
            builder.Append(bite.ToString("X2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

... where `BuildEntityTypeDescription()` is a method that builds a string from the type's navigation properties, key members etc.

So, basically, the proxy type name is a hashed representation of the type's meta data, so it will always be the same string as long as the type doesn't change.